# How do you write the typing reference for this using rules from simply typed lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have to give the typing derivation for this particular statement

• ` λf : unit → (unit × unit).fst (f ()) : (unit → (unit × unit)) → unit.

I am super new to this and don't understand why it will just lead to unit at the end.
Shouldn't it be

unit -> unit x unit -> unit -> unit x unit.